# os.join creates the wrong path

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

I need to get the absolute path to a directory on my desktop
I have :

```
 home = os.environ["HOMEPATH"]
 desktop =  os.path.join(home,'Desktop')
 name = 'Test_L1_R1
 fileName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(desktop,r'\python35\connect4\pons\data',name))
```

The result should be

```
C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\python35\connect4\pons\data\Test_L1_R1
```

But the actual result is

```
C:\python35\connect4\pons\data\Test_L1_R1
```

I believe that os is detecting that I have a directory

```
C:\python35
```

because if I change the path to

```
fileName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(desktop,r'\connect4\pons\data',name))
```

ie remove the python35 part I get the correct answer

How do I stop it doing that?

Comment: Remove `abspath`? If you know what you are doing it, you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

Stop using an absolute path in the second argument.

Comment: I am afraid that did not work. I still get :C:\python35\connect4\pons\data\Test_L1_R1 Note "desktop" is C:\Users\Alan\Desktop

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand you - I jumped to the idea that I should stop using os.path.abspath but did you mean change "r'\python35\connect4\pons\data'". How should I change it?

Comment: Remove the initial backslash. That makes it an absolute path.